# Why does SQL Server not follow BODMAS mathematics rules with SUM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I came across a very confusing issue with a legacy stored procedure yesterday, and while I've "fixed" it, I don't feel I understand why it was needed.

> BODMAS - The order of mathematical operations:
>
> Brackets, Order, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction

So, Addition happens before Subtraction. Technically they are equally weighted and happen "at the same time" because they typically counter each other out.

With that agreed, we should be able to agree that the following are all true:

- 1000 - (300 + 300) = 400
- 1000 - 300 + 300 = 400
- (1000 - 300) + 300 = 1000

However, SQL evaluates the middle one as 1000. I can easily remedy this by adding brackets. My concern is that while this example is clean and simple, when the numbers 300 are coming from Coalesced Sums, there's already a lot of brackets flying around. It's entirely feasible that they could get removed accidentally, by someone following BODMAS logic, or if marked as redundant in a code optimiser.

Here's some code to try it for yourself

```
CREATE TABLE #TempData ([Number] INT)

INSERT INTO #TempData VALUES(200)
INSERT INTO #TempData VALUES(100)

SELECT 1000 - (SUM(Number) + SUM(Number))
FROM #TempData

SELECT 1000 - SUM(Number) + SUM(Number)
FROM #TempData

SELECT (1000 - SUM(Number)) + SUM(Number)
FROM #TempData

DROP TABLE #TempData
```

Comment: `1000 - (300 + 300)` is not the same as `1000 - 300 + 300`

Comment: `1000 - (300 + 300) = 600` - I don't know of anyone who would agree that this was true.

Comment: The same with 1000 - 300 + 300 = 600 ... seems to me that it is 1000 and the SQL gives the right result

Comment: I'm not overly fond of "BODMAS" as a mnemonic. The German version *Punkt vor Strich* ("dots before strokes") is much neater: It tells you that `⋅` (multiplication) and `:` (division) (the "dotty" operators) are processed before `+` (addition) and `-` (subtraction) (the operators written with strokes), and it does not imply that `+` is done before `-` or `-` before `+`.

Comment: I can't believe I got the maths wrong! Sorry, should have been 400. I even had the SQL output to copy from *eyeroll* - corrected now

Comment: `1000 - 300 + 300 = 400` is still wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> 1000 - 300 + 300 = 400
> ```

This is wrong.

As you said, `+` and `-` are equally weighted and happen at the same time. By convention, the basic operations are all left associative, so multiple operators of the same weight in a row are processed from left to right:

```
1000 - 300 + 300 = ((1000 - 300) + 300
```

This is true everywhere (mathematics, SQL, most programming languages), so the issue is not a difference between SQL and conventional mathematical notation but a misunderstanding of the convention.

Comment: Yes, it should have been `= 400`. A significant typo

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation of BODMAS is simply incorrect.  The Multiplication/division and addition/subtraction are not actually ordered, they are equivalent and evaluated from the left.

This point is specifically addressed in Wikipedia:

> For example, using [BODMAS] in the order "addition first,
>   subtraction afterward" would incorrectly evaluate the expression[6]
>
> ```
> 10 − 3 + 2.
> ```
>
> The correct value is 9 (and not 5, as if the addition would be carried
>   out first and the result used with the subtraction afterwards).

Comment: I don't think my interpretation is wrong, more that BODMAS should not be used. BODMAS only exists as an easy way to remember the order, but if it has caveats that can change the order, therefore not informing you of the order, it has failed in its purpose. We need an English equivalent to the German one.